# Cakephp 3 Cake\Network\Email configTransport Issue

Tags: email, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cake\Network\Email\Email class to send some emails.

I have successfully send an email with my smtp configuration that I put on config/app.php

The problem is that I don't want the config to be there.
I have this piece of code:

```
    function enviacorreo($email, $asunto, $content, $cc=null) {

    Email::configTransport('gmail', [
        'port'=>$smtpport,
        'timeout'=>'30',
        'host' => $smtp,
        'username'=>$smtpuser,
        'password'=>$smtppasswd
    ]);
    $email_obj = new Email();

    $email_obj->template('default')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->to($email)
        ->from([$smtpuser => $nombreSistema])
        ->subject($asunto)
        ->transport('gmail');

    if($email_obj->send($content))
        return array('exito'=>1,'error'=>'Ninguno');
    else
        return array('exito'=>0,'error'=>'El correo no pudo ser enviado');
}
```

I'm following the official book [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports)
The error that I get is this:

> Transport config "gmail" is missing.

I know that `->transport('gmail');` is looking for a key inside the `EmailTransport` array definded in app.php
But. How can I have this 'configuration' in my code?

Hope to explained well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is a little misleading, as the exception is not only being thrown in case the configuration missing, but also in case the `className` option is missing, which is the case in your example (**[#7204](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7204)**).

If you look closely at the docs, you should see that you haven't followed it correctly.

> [...]
>
> ```php
> // Sample smtp configuration.
> Email::configTransport('gmail', [
>     'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
>     'port' => 465,
>     'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
>     'password' => 'secret',
>     'className' => 'Smtp' // <------ there it is
> ]);
> ```
>
> [...]

**[Cookbook > Email > Configuring Transports](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports)**

Comment: I was trying a bunch of combinations and none of them include the 'className' attribute defined. A very important detail that I just forgot.

Even in the app.php file says:  Each transport needs a `className`.. lol